# angular2 how to scope providers differently for peers

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

app.module has logger provider

injectable logger requires http from DI

so app.module must provide http to DI for logger

app.module bootstraps app.component

app.component requires logger from DI

but app.component should never be allowed to require http from DI

How to have peer components not be able to require a peer required?

Comment: Please, don't try to describe the code. Post it instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prevent a component from declaring and including a dependency from Angular's DI. Usually this would just be handled by coding standards (i.e., don't do it).

If you really want to ensure nobody on the team does this unintentionally or unknowingly you can create a source control hook to scan code for disallowed injections by file name convention. There's nothing built-in to do it for you though.

Comment: OK, thank you. A bit different than what I am used to, e.g. where it is impossible for the UI to get to the ORM, it has to use the service layer.